# Does not receive event from Stripe Webhook

Tags: c#, azure, stripe-payments, .net-6.0, webhooks

I am integrating Stripe to my project and this is my flow to charge user

1. User will add the payment card to my system for charging (I will store the customer id and payment method id)
2. When user confirm to charge by which payment card, a payment intent will be created

```
var paymentIntentOptions = new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
{
    PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>
    {
        "card"
    },
    Amount = (long)unitAmount,
    Currency = "usd",
    Customer = input.CustomerId,
    PaymentMethod = input.PaymentMethodId,
    Confirm = true,
    OffSession = true,
};
var requestOptions = new RequestOptions { IdempotencyKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };
var paymentIntentService = new PaymentIntentService();
var createPaymentIntentResult = await paymentIntentService.CreateAsync(paymentIntentOptions, requestOptions, cancellationToken);
```

3. Then I have Stripe Webhook listening to the event of charging successfully for other actions

```
case Events.ChargeSucceeded:
    {
        // handle logic
        break;
    }
default:
    _logger.LogInformation("Unhandled event type: {0}", stripeEvent.Type);
    break;
```

4. In the Stripe Dashboard I received these messages
   [image]

Everything works just fine in the local. However, It does not receive the event from webhook when being deployed to Azure

I dont know if the way I implemented is correct. Any answer will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: By the way could I bypass the handle action for this event [`payment_intent.requires_payment_method`](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/paymentintents/lifecycle) if I set the a specific value for the field `PaymentMethod` and set the field `Confirm` to be `true` in the `PaymentIntentCreateOptions` object

Comment: You would need to elaborate on how it does not receive the event when deployed to Azure. Have you setup the Azure URL into Stripe Dashboard?

Write to Stripe Support with concrete code. They should be able to help.